# Parent module to link to sub modules - generated by sub-module

Tags: 8

I've got a parent module that shows a list of functionality available from its sub modules. I'd like the links shown related to sub-modules to be added by the sub-modules themselves rather than being hard coded into the parent module (although they are generated using the route name).

The reason for this is so sub-modules are responsible for showing their functionality through the parent based on the users permissions and that work is self contained. Also means if a sub-module is disabled there won't be any dead links in the parent.

Comment: I have to agree with @EricLavault, I've not gotten back to the answer / marked as correct as I've been away and unable to implement to check it meets what is in my question.

Comment: So far, the post merely describes what you are trying to achieve, without making any explicit question, nor making clear what exactly you don't understand. The described task is too broad to be answered and the answer could be to implement an hook that is already used from a module, use a new hook, or use an event subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

This is an opportunity to create your own hook.

In the parent module, let's say the function responsible to provide the list of functionalities is your hook function.

In this function, you need to invoke modules providing the functionalities, thus meaning your submodules have to implement the hook in order to expose their features.

For example, in your main module :

```
/**
 * Shows a list of functionalities available from other modules
 */
function mainmodule_get_functionalities_list () {
  $list = \Drupal::moduleHandler()->invokeAll('list_functionalities');
  # Here filter the list based on user permissions, unless you have a good reason
  # to do it in each submodule (like if the permission is provided by the submodule, 
  # the parent may not be aware of it, or it means harcode). 
  return $list;
}
```

And in a submodule :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_functionalities_list
 */
function submodule_functionalities_list () {
  return [
    'some functionality',
    'awesome submodule functionality',
    #'etc.'
  ];
}
```

Note : hook_functionalities_list implementation is not restricted to submodules. If you really need to, you might want to invoke submodule "manually", that is : using `\Drupal::moduleHandler()->getImplementations($hook);`, filter the implementation list based on (sub)module naming, and foreach one make the call.